# Boto create launch configuration in different VPC with fabric and boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I keep getting this error returned from my boto create_launch_configuration() cmd wrapped in a fabric task.

This is the cmd:

```
if user_data != '':
security_groups=list('sg-d73fc5b2')

print "Trying to use this AMI [%s]" % image_ami

lc = LaunchConfiguration(
  name=launch_config_name,
  image_id=image_ami,
  key_name=env.aws_key_name,
  security_groups=security_groups,
  instance_type=instance_type
)

launch_config = autoscale_conn.create_launch_configuration(lc)
```

and this is the response

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://autoscaling.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-01-01/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>ValidationError</Code>
        <Message>No default VPC for this user</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>4371fa63-e008-11e3-8554-ff532bce5053</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

We disabled the default VPC in order to try and minimise mistakes being applied to a VPC via API calls. We have several VPC's running from the same account and it would be useful to be able to specify the VPC via boto.

Has anyone any idea how I can set this default VPC on a per task basis?

Comment: What is the value of ``sec_groups``?  Is it a list of security group names or is it a list of security group IDs?

Comment: I have slightly edited the example. If you check above now it should be a little more explanatory now.

Comment: Is this the way you instantiate security_groups? Cause this will create a list of characters, not list consisting of one string.

Comment: You are completely right. I hadn't realised it was creating a list of characters not a list of strings. The fix was simply ['sg-2728228']

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/asg-in-vpc.html) you should specify a subnet when creating auto-scaling group. And though it is not stated that you have to have default VPC for creating launch configuration, I would say that reading [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/autoscalingsubnets.html). Particularly this lines:

> If your AWS account comes with a default VPC and if you want to create your Auto Scaling group in default VPC, follow the instructions in ...

So you just need to create auto-scaling group in the desired subnet and use your launch configuration for this group.